# How to implement rejection sampling in R?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, sampling, statistical-sampling

I have a dataset of rows of genes each with their gene length, I am looking to sample from these genes by their gene length distribution using rejection sampling - as I have too many genes in this dataset that are too small to enter further analysis (but I can't just set a cut-off on my own to remove them). I have 1 dataset of genes with gene lengths to sample from, and another proposal distribution of gene lengths that I want to use in order to do the rejection sampling of the first dataset.

An example of my data looks like this:

```
#df1 data to sample from:
Gene  Length
Gene1  5
Gene2  6
Gene3  400000
Gene4  1000
Gene5  25000
Gene6  10
Gene7  50
Gene8  4
Gene9  100
Gene10 2000
```

My proposal dataset:

```
#df2
Gene  Length
Gene1  5000
Gene2  60000
Gene3  400000
Gene4  1000
Gene5  25000
Gene6  10000
Gene7  50000
Gene8  4000
Gene9  1000
Gene10 2000
```

I don't have any statistics background, and I am trying to perform rejection sampling (my overall aim is to get a sample of genes with less extremely small genes in length to take onto further analysis).

To do rejection sampling I am trying this from a tutorial I found [here](https://rpubs.com/mathetal/rejectsampling):

```
X = df1$Length
U = df2$Length

accept = c()
count = 1

pi_x <- function(x) {
  new_x = (3/2)*(x^3)+(11/8)*(x^2)+(1/6)*(x)+(1/12)
  return(new_x)
}


while(count <= 50 & length(accept) < 50){
  test_u = U[count]
  test_x = pi_x(X[count])/(3.125*dunif(X[count],0,1))
  if (test_u <= test_x){
    accept = rbind(accept, X[count])
    count = count + 1
  }
  count = count + 1
}
```

My problem with this is that it only selects 25 genes (my ideal sampling range for further analysis is 50-100 genes being selected) and most of these 25 genes are still very small in size after sampling. Is it that I need to transform `X` in some way before running this rejection sampling code? My actual data for `df1` is 800 genes with a skewed/beta distribution of gene length (most are very small). Or am I completely missing something else in my understanding? Any guidance at all would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10"), Length = c(5L, 
6L, 400000L, 1000L, 25000L, 10L, 50L, 4L, 100L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10"), Length = c(5000L, 
60000L, 400000L, 1000L, 25000L, 10000L, 50000L, 40000L, 1000L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Edit:

I have also tried:

```
sampled <- data.frame(proposal = df2$Length)
sampled$targetDensity <- dbeta(sampled$proposal, 3,6)

maxDens = max(sampled$targetDensity, na.rm = T)
sampled$accepted = ifelse(df1$Length < sampled$targetDensity / maxDens, TRUE, FALSE)

hist(sampled$proposal[sampled$accepted], freq = F, col = "grey", breaks = 100)
curve(dbeta(x, 3,6),0,1, add =T, col = "red")
```

But I am certain I am not using `dbeta()` correctly since `sampled$targetDensity` outputs all zeros - is there a way I can fix this? I have tried changing the values in `dbeta()` but haven't had any success.

Comment: What is your target distribution? In your example code you seem to use the density function from the tutorial, but I guess that cannot be what you wanted.
If you would like to sample the genes based on their length (i.e. longer genes have higher probability to be chosen) then I would suggest to just use base-R's `sample()` function instead of trying to implement rejection sampling yourself (which would be an overkill in this case anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of genes you want to sample, the sample function should work fine:

```
sampled = sample(df$genes, size = n, prob = df$length)
```

if you want to reduce even more the probability of sampling a gene with a small length, you can square the length for the `prob` argument. The argument prob is associating a sampling probability to each element (here based on the length)

If you don't know the number of genes you want to obtain, then you can define your own probability function:

```
rejection.prob = function(x){
  if (x<too.small) {return(0)} # all genes smaller than too.small won't be sampled
  if (x > it.is.ok) {return(1)} # all these ones will be sampled
  if (x>too.small & (x<it.is.ok){
    # here make any function that is equal to 0 when x == too.small
    # and 1 when x == it.is.ok
    # it can be a simple linear function
}
```

note that you can also use the output of the `rejection.prob` function for the `sample` function.

Depending on what you expect, you might want to have your rejection function to be more continuous (without these breaks at too.small and it.is.ok). If it's the case, I would use a sigmoid function where you can tune your parameters depending on the desired output.

Comment: How does the custom function in your answer help if OP doesn't know the number of genes to obtain? I would argue that you cannot use any sampling method if you don't know how many samples you'd like to obtain.

Comment: Using the ```sample()``` function and squaring the gene length as the ```prob``` looks like it gives me a sample I can use (I have a rough idea the number of samples I want so I can set a number for now). My only question is just for my understanding of the stats - why does squaring reduce the chance of smaller genes? Is there a stats resource where I can go to teach myself if the answer is a simple one?

Comment: @DN1 Squaring increases the ratio between the lengths, it has nothing to do with statistics. Example: length 90 is 10 times as large as length 9 (and so will be chosen 10 times as likely). But length 90^2=8100 is 100 times as large as 9^2 = 81 (and will as such be chosen 100 times as likely).

Comment: @DN1 Note that from a statistics perspective it makes absolutely no sense to create your data this way. If you have a target distribution that is known as meaningful from previous research, sampling is a good strategy. But just altering the weights (e.g. by squaring) until the result "looks good" is borderline to falsifying the data. It would be much better to just choose a certain cut-off if you want to remove genes. At least this way it is clear what happend and why it happend; even if the cut-off cannot be theoretically justified.